# How do I move the button from one position to another?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a button at x position when the view is loaded, and when a button is clicked I want the button to go right under a text field. I don't want to use static points like (1,2) instead I want to use the position of the text field and shift the button up or down relative to that text field. Any help is appreciated.

```
  @IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var log: UIButton!
  name.addTarget(self, action: "name:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingDidBegin)
```

When a text field is clicked, I want the button to move to below the name text field. Currently nothing happens when I click the text field.

```
  func name(sender: UITextField){
  var y: Int = Int(name.frame.origin.y)
  var x: Int = Int(name.frame.origin.x)
  log.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y - 50, width: 157, height: 40)
}
```

Comment: Have you implemented a tap gesture recognizer for the text field?

Comment: Yes I have, and it works

Comment: If you want the button to move when the user starts editing the text in the text field, you can simply use the delegate of the textfield instead of adding a tap gesture. In the delegation method, you can set the position of the button.

Comment: I'm not using a tap gesture check out the updated code

Comment: I am using autolayout in storyboard if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

I would create an `@IBOutlet` to a `NSLayoutConstraint` that links the center of the button to the center of the text field. In Interface Builder, you can set the initial distance between the two objects as you please. In your action (or delegate method) you just change the `constant` of the constraint.

```
distanceConstraint.constant = 0
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) { self.view.layoutIfNeeded() }
```

Similarly, set the constant back to the original distance when you want to show the button again.